# Points in convex d-dimensional polytope

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, polygons

Given a set of points, and a convex d-dimensional polytope represented only by a set of its' vertices, I need to query in order to check for each point if it's inside the polytope. I know of the O(log(n)) solution in 2D (like the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135978/show-that-given-a-query-point-q-it-can-be-tested-in-time-olog-n-whether-q-li), but I can't figure out how to implement it in arbitrary dimensions, without the use of cross-product, and without knowing if I can still use the same method - maybe the sorting gives the expected behavior only in 2 dimensions.

Can anyone give me some insight on this problem?

My current solution is given m points to query and a polytope represented by n vertices, I am solving m linear programs with n variables each, which represent finding out if there exists a convex combination of the vertices which equals the current query point. This solution is O(mn), and I'm looking for something faster, if it exists.

Comment: Which 2D method are you referring to ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust https://cp-algorithms.com/geometry/point-in-convex-polygon.html

Comment: If no preprocessing is allowed, I guess that the point-in-convex-polyhedron problem has complexity $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust since I need to check multiple points, I can preprocess the polytope once for O(n), and then answer each query in O(log(n)) time. Such algorithm will be great for me, but is it possible in arbitrary dimensions?

Comment: That's also something you forgot to mention.

Comment: There is a claim that queries can be performed in constant time for polygons and polyhedra in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2208/2208.03682.pdf. That might generalize.

Comment: Please don't provide clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question so it reads well and all relevant information is in your post.  (Even better yet, include that information from the start so people don't have to ask for clarification.)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/155671/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4584470/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).